# how to prevent constructor to make singleton instance in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to prevent constructor to make singleton instance in javascript

```
var Singleton = (function () {
var instance;

function createInstance() {
    var object = new Object("I am the instance");
    return object;
}

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = createInstance();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
})();

function run() {

   var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
   var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

   alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));  
}
```

Comment: The above is an implementation of the singleton pattern. So why you use it if you don't want to make use of a singleton? I am sorry but I don't get what you try to do. Could you please provide an example of what you want to do. Thanks

Comment: "how to prevent constructor to make singleton instance in javascript?" this is the question.

Comment: The code you posted should work. The constructor cannot be invoked more than once (because it is not visible to outside code).

Comment: The only constructor with the usual usage of the term is this `new Object("I am the instance");` If you refer to the `createInstance` function this is defined in the scope of Singleton function and since it's is not exposed like `getInstance` cannot be called outside of the Singleton. On the other hand if you want `getInstance` returns a new instance each time you could add a boolean argument which would ovveried the `!instance`. When you request `getInstance(true)` then would return a new instance each time, whereas when you request `getInstance(false)` you would get the singleton instance.

Comment: If that's the case I have to admitt that this should have been one of the most **odd** design decisions I have ever seen, since the singleton pattern is used for a specific reason, to provider the caller of your code with a single instance of an object. If this is not that you, I don't see why you make use of it.

Comment: @Amit If you just want `instance1 === instance2` to evaluate to `false` then just remove `if` condition from `getInstance` method.